# RmiClient ServerError

Tags: java, rmi

I am getting this error below:

> RmiClient exception: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server
>   thread; nested exception is: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

If I press the button which is going to communicate with the server on the same system each time I am getting the error as follows:

```
RmiClient exception: java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nest
ed exception is:
        java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ServerGUI.getMessage(Ljava/lang/String;J)
Ljava/lang/String;
java.rmi.ServerError: Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
        java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ServerGUI.getMessage(Ljava/lang/String;J)
Ljava/lang/String;
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknow
n Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at ServerGUI_Stub.getMessage(Unknown Source)
        at RmiClient.getMessage(RmiClient.java:13)
        at ButtonController.actionPerformed(ButtonController.java:15)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It's difficult to help with this because you haven't included any code, or even any description of what you're trying to do.  I can tell you that the method being invoked is not implemented (abstract), but that's about as far as I can get you without more information.  Also, it looks like you've posted the same huge stack trace twice

Comment: @Floegipoky There's nothing mysterious about an AbstractMethodError. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to tell by just looking at your stack trace. but make sure you extend the server class with Thread and also implement the following in your client class.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
   public void run(){
    //////// do something with the client window frame
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but I need some Little bit of code Implementation or some of the site from where that I can get some Examples. As I am new to RMI I want to learn some more.

Comment: Have you tried using Google? You know, you can type two words into Google, like "rmi examples".

Comment: This is all irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

You've changed something without recompiling everything or redeploying. Probably the signature of he remote method. Do a clean build and redeploy.